# Pure JavaScript Library for Geometry Operations

Tags: javascript, software-recommendations, open-source-gis

Does anyone know of a pure JavaScript library for doing geometry operations such as buffer, union, intersects, etc?

I want to play with doing these operations in the browser.  It looks like GeoScriptJS has some dependencies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could look at the OpenLayers API, particularly the [Geometry classes](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html). You can check for intersects, and have access to vertices etc. 
I've implemented point buffers in the past just with OpenLayers. Unions may be trickier though.

For more complex operations you may want to do the processing server-side, and pass results back in WKT or GeoJSON, both of which OpenLayers can display. See this [Union tutorial](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-spatialdbtips/click-union.html) for an example.

Another possible option is [Spatial Query](https://github.com/netshade/spatial_query) a "*JQuery like Javascript library for handling spatial maths*." I'm not sure how well tested it is but as the source is available you should take a look.

**Update**

There is now a JavaScript port of the JTS Topology Suite - https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

Comment: I looked at OpenLayers geometries, and I think that the resize method would allow me to scale the geometries to get buffer-like results.  But you're right, doing unions and intersections would all have to be done manually.  Alas.  What I really need is a pure JS port of JTS.  JSTS? =)

Answer (score 25):

I'm pretty much done with my port of JTS which is a pure JS port and it's available at https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

At the current version (0.9.1) it supports the core functionality of JTS by which I mean predicates and overlays.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look on [geoscript](http://geoscript.org/js/index.html) (implemented in severals langauages including JS)

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for Google AppEngine, from what I read, [JTS is officially compatible with Google App Engine](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2010/02/jts-and-google-app-engine.html). There is a basic demo at http://giscloud.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Turf](https://github.com/turfjs/turf) is a javascript library providing a lot of spatial operations. It is also modular, so you can only include the functions you need in the final script.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, for reference on similar questions, there is also the [Geometry.js library](https://github.com/HarryStevens/geometric) (first release in 2019) that could fit for some needs, complementary with the nice JSTS library.
It is pretty straight-forward for getting the area of polygons, calculating angles and scaling operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ArcGIS server REST API regardless of which API/language you are using. It provides all the methods exposed....

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to opensource javascript geometry library @ [geoJs](https://github.com/sunny-luthra/geoJs.git).