# How to get the intersecting polygon of two polygons? (using JSTS intersection)

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, intersection

I want to intersect two polygons within an OpenLayers layer. I found the [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) library, which should be able to intersect two polygons, and return the new created polygon of the intersection.
The function to use: [intersection](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/blob/master/src/jsts/geom/Geometry.js#L1017)

```
polygon1.intersection(polygon2)
```

Using the OpenLayers Polygons directly, I get errors, resulting of the missing functions, added by JSTS. And if I use JSTS Polygons, there seems still something missing.
`this.getFactory().createGeometryCollection is not a function`

How do I get an intersection of those two polygons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [intersects](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.intersects) method in OpenLayers will only return a boolean value, not the intersection of the features.

```
if(polygon1.intersects(polygon2)){
   //polygons intersect
```

*Edit*: I see you mean using the OpenLayers polygon type rather than the OpenLayers intersect method.

The JSTS library has only been out a few days, and the intersects function you referenced was updated 6 hours ago, so not sure how stable it is at the moment.

Comment: You are right. I just want to use the OpenLayers polygon type. I need the actual coordinates of the new intersection. Thanks pointing out that JSTS is still very fresh.

Comment: @happly - I downloaded it a couple of days ago and couldn't get the unit tests to run, I'll try again in a week, but I wouldn't rely on it for a production system yet. Probably best to do it server-side for the moment

Comment: hmm, I could use it so much now. Thanks. You don't now any mature client-based solutions?

Comment: @happly - not really.. see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/pure-javascript-library-for-geometry-operations/7173#7173